# Symfony 3 - Form collection - Fixed amount of sets

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

Let's assume, that I have form which has, among others, one field of `collection` type. How to force from that field to open fixed amount of subfields sets when page is loaded in browser (not adding by clicking <kbd>Add another item</kbd> button)?

```
/**
 * @Assert\Valid
 * @Assert\Count(min="1")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="PageBundle\Entity\Page\PageLocale",
 *     mappedBy="page",
 *     cascade={"persist","remove"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 * @var Page\PageLocale[]
 */
protected $locales;
```

Whole code in this repository: [LINK](https://github.com/ktrzos/SymfonyBasic/tree/master/src/Notimeo/PageBundle). Look at `Entity/Page.php` and `Entity/Page/PageLocale.php`. Collection form is in `Form/PageLocaleType.php`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you well. Do you want to render fixed amount of `PageLocale` **subforms** on page load?

Comment: Yes. But not with JavaScript and `onLoad`. Only with a simple page refresh or just page loaded in browser. For now, when I want to add new entity on "Add page" form, I see only `Add another item` button and 0 items in that collection. In result I want to see, for example, one set of subform without clicking this button.

Comment: So if it's fixed amount of subforms, why can't you simply add them? I guess we  need more detailed information here, because it can be done in several ways depending on exact expected result.

Comment: Ok, but how? It's a [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) in other form and it should have possibility to contain minimum of 1 it's items and more. I can't just programmatically create it... i think :/.

Comment: Could you provide suitable code? I guess you can handle it with form events.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but don't know how to present this in other words. Still newb in Symfony :/.

Comment: @dragoste Updated question. Added links to the whole code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110478/discussion-between-dragoste-and-krzysztof-trzos).